# Fiddler Website web request Mimicking for screen scraping

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to log into a website to download data through my account. This is the raw Fiddler Request for the POST login form.

```
POST login/login.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: server.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 73
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://server.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://server.com/login/login.jsp
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=109610308.114257620.1370889472.1373479499.1371761934.3; __utmc=109613338; __utmz=109610308.1373249472.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _bcvm_vid_424161365915852877=4393500994580715020; _bcvm_vrid_424161365915852877=4393492275825713189; WT_FPC=id=199.234.233.42-2645888112.30303753:lv=1371356395815:ss=1371758333825; JSESSIONID=RGJGy4yQ2WCXRPbnhxCTKGb2rZh39b67d8g8PktTQLqfsBQTlTlYLTD!1154156211; BIGipServeresuite_prod_pool=295635768.2713643.0000
```

It then responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 12:39:46 GMT
Location: https://server.com/login/redirect.jsp?APPLICATION=0
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: SECURITY_SESSION_ID=383826514*198399234219875960; domain=.server.com; path=/
Connection: Close
Set-Cookie: BIGipServeresuite_prod_pool=294168768.27163.0000; expires=Fri, 21-Jun-2013 13:09:47 GMT; path=/
Content-Length: 3669
```

That SECURITY_SESSION_ID is what's needed to do anything on the site.

To mimic it I coded wrote this:

```
   //GET the Login page - I preform a quick get to pick up the first two important cookies

          HttpWebRequest GETLoginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://server.com/login/login.jsp");
          GETLoginRequest.Method = "GET";
          GETLoginRequest.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
          GETLoginRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
          GETLoginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
          GETLoginRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;  

          HttpWebResponse GETLoginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)GETLoginRequest.GetResponse(); //Gets the JSession and BIGipServer cookies
          Console.Write(" \n 3rd count after GETLoginResponse : " + cookieJar.Count + "\n");

 //POST Login

          HttpWebRequest POSTLoginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://server.com/login/login.jsp");
          POSTLoginRequest.Method = "POST";
          WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = POSTLoginRequest.Headers;
          POSTLoginRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
          byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);

       ///Cache
          POSTLoginRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0"); 

        //Client
          POSTLoginRequest.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
          POSTLoginRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate,sdch"); 
          myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language:en-US");
          POSTLoginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
        //Cookies/Login
          POSTLoginRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar; //The cookie jar contains mainly added
        //Entity
          POSTLoginRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
          POSTLoginRequest.ContentType = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //Miscellanous
          POSTLoginRequest.Headers.Add("Origin: https://server.com");
          POSTLoginRequest.Referer = "https://server.com/login/login.jsp";
        //Transport

              //Fix I found to allow Connection: Keep-Alive
          var sp = POSTLoginRequest.ServicePoint;
          var prop = sp.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
          prop.SetValue(sp, (byte)0, null);

          ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

          POSTLoginRequest.Host = "server.com";

          using (Stream os = POSTLoginRequest.GetRequestStream())
          {
              os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
          }
          HttpWebResponse POSTLoginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)POSTLoginRequest.GetResponse();
          Console.Write(" \n 4th count after POSTLoginResponse : " + cookieJar.Count + "\n");
```

at the end of the day my request in fiddler looks like this:

```
 POST /login/login.jsp HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://server.com
Referer: https://server.com/login/login.jsp
Host: esuite.pjm.com
Cookie: __utma=1096103034.235016339.1371048460.1371048460.1371048460.1; __utmz=109610428.1371048460.1.1.utmcsr=bing|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=pjm; _bcvm_vrid_424161365915852877=4393493862784729423; WT_FPC=id=199.234.233.42-3603288592.30304123:lv=1371044861062:ss=1371044859892; JSESSIONID=RGbYQd7JnPdNkTvtGCzQ9NLyFgfBnnyLFzbvKPg2Y0gLnhL2hp8F!-1770592471; BIGipServeresuite_prod_pool=327723200.27163.0000
Content-Length: 73
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

which is pretty much the same and yet I get this as a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 13:58:17 GMT
Content-Length: 3356
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: BIGipServeresuite_prod_pool=327723200.27163.0000; expires=Fri, 21-Jun-2013 14:28:17 GMT; path=/
```

I think one thing has to do with that in the browser the reply is a 302 Moved Temporarily but I really don't know. The two important cookies seem to be JSession and BIGIp because
those are set by the site. The other cookies I manually added in and they seem to be google analytic cookies and I don't think they matter all to much. Anyway the headers are nearly
identicaly but it's still not responding with the SECURITY_SESSION_ID that I'm looking for. Does anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using CURLLib ? AS i have faced this issue with getting cookies from https pages many time.And if you like to continue using HTTPWEBREQUEST just copy the cookies to container and you are good to go.And let me know if  you need sample code its easy.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use CURLLib I just used fiddler and followed it all correctly. I read that you should always place AllowAutoRedirect = false.... This isnt always the case. Sometimes you should set it to True. It depends on the website. Everything in the code snippet in my code above was set to false (that had to do with AllowAutoRedirect). then in the request after it was set to true and it worked. :D

Comment: curlib is not like fiddler but httpwebrequest which works without even duplicating all the requests i wrote the function once and i just change the url to get,post and it works perfectly fine you should also check that out , it has also support for multithreading inside you can send an array of urls with or without post parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'accept' headers are different, and your Content-Type part of the submit is wrong:

```
POSTLoginRequest.ContentType = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Should be

```
POSTLoginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I changed it. What a silly mistake in regards to the ContentType. :| Anyway it still doesn't reply with the proper cookie

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the post parameters are the same as in fiddler example:

So do this first before converting them to bytes.

```
HttpUtility.Urlencode(forumparameters)
```

See if that works.

As you are missing counts in ContentLength too, so must be cause of this.